# Not able to run the SimpleApp program of Google Could big-query using maven as mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.bigquery.SimpleApp

Tags: google-bigquery

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory
        at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.(JacksonFactory.java:44)
        at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory$InstanceHolder.(JacksonFactory.java:64)

Comment: Github location of the code https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/bigquery/SimpleApp.java

Comment: Please add your code here.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the older versions of jackson-core jars from my local maven repository and then run the code and it worked